# The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5' was not found while Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 is found

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5, asp.net5

when I use the dotnet command I have an issue

```
> dotnet Mydll.dll
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      2.1.23 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.2.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      2.2.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.0.3 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.9 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      3.1.10 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      5.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      5.0.7 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=5&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

I am a little suprised cause it seems I have the the runtime Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 installed and also the 5.0.7

```
>dotnet --list-runtimes

Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.23 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
```

I have installed the Hosting Bundle of ASP.NET Core Runtime 5.0.7 for being sure but still have the issue

Would you have an idea nout what is the issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uninstall deprecated package globally:-

```
dotnet tool uninstall dotnet-ef -g
```

And then try to Reinstall the up-to-date package version:-

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.1
```

**If not work, try to second process:-**

So you have already installed .Net 5.

download [dotnet-sdk-5.0.301-win-x64.zip](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/5.0) and copied `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.301` folder manually from the zip file to `C:\ProgramFiles\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.301`

then hope the asp.net core application will be started working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I added the following line to `.csproj` file manually:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of issue when trying to start my application from Visual Studio.

**Update you Visual Studio** using Visual Studio Installer solved this for me.

Direct download installer places the files in this folder

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`

And Visual Studio installer places the files in this folder

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App`